# Chartjs wrong automatic y-Axis scale

Tags: chart.js

the automatic scaling of the y-axis does not seem to work properly. I have the following code:

```
<script>
$(function () {
    var lineChartCanvas = $('#lineChart').get(0).getContext('2d')
    var lineChartData = {
        datasets: [
            {
                label: 'Digital Goods',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(60,141,188,0.9)',
                borderColor: 'rgba(60,141,188,0.8)',
                pointRadius: false,
                pointColor: '#3b8bba',
                pointStrokeColor: 'rgba(60,141,188,1)',
                pointHighlightFill: '#ffffff',
                pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(60,141,188,1)',
                data: {{data}}
            },
        ]
    }
    var lineChartOptions = {
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        responsive: true,
        legend: {
            display: false
        },
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                gridLines: {
                    display: false,
                }
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                gridLines: {
                    display: false,
                }
            }]
        }
    }

    var lineChart = new Chart(lineChartCanvas, {
        type: 'line',
        data: lineChartData,
        options: lineChartOptions
    })
});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqGZM.jpg)

The graphs yaxes goes till 5, however, there is no data bigger than 1. I would like it to be more precise (y-axes not higher than 1 or something). However, as this code is part of a bigger application, I cannot set a fixed max as the code differs per scenario.

I tried to add an example, however, the data is not exactly like that (orginially 8760 values) and in this example another problem comes up. My lib is jquery.min.js (https://jsfiddle.net/742ovrLm/)

Comment: Please add a [mre]!

Comment: What version of the lib are you using, because with your code it works just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/Leelenaleee/emprwf36/9/

Comment: I am using jquery.min.js